# How can I set Dolphin to be the default file manager in KDE?

Tags: linux, debian, kde

After one of the recent upgrades of my Debian Testing the default file manager in KDE switched from Dolphin to Konqueror for some reason. How can I switch it back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In KDE's settings manager (kcontrol), you should find a "Default Applications" entry under "Workspace Appearance and Behaviour". There, you can alter the default file manager.