# How to make Dolphin the default file manager on RHEL 8?

Tags: rhel, gnome-shell, file-manager, dolphin, gnome-classic

I installed Dolphin successfully, its icon is in *Application* → *System Tools* and it works well.

But, in *Settings* → *Details* → *Default Applications* there's everything else just not *File Manager*. Why this? Isn't managing files one of the main task`s on a desktop OS? And aren't personal file handling preferences as numerous as different OSs?

I found:

- [How can I set Dolphin to be the default file manager in KDE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40858/88374)
- [How to make Konqueror to be the default file manager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345169/88374)

but those didn't help me in my case. How can I achieve this somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

Found this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50386#issuecomment-1035081994)

Install `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-kde`.

Open the terminal and run the commands:

```bsh
xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory

xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Insert the option to the file `defaults.list`:

```bsh
echo "inode/directory=org.kde.dolphin.desktop" >> $HOME/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Run the command `sudo nano /etc/environment` and insert `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1`;

Restart your computer.

Comment: I fixed your comment. No need to modify the root's `default.list`, he can define the user's `default.list`. Remember you need to clear the caches and the cookies. I am the author of the tutorial.